# How to update from conda 4.3 installed in base environment?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have updated (or installed) conda to a version which is higher than 4.3, but for testing purposes, I installed conda=4.3. Now, I cannot update conda back to a higher version with the `base` environment activated.

```
$ conda update conda

PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /home/user/miniconda3/envs/base
  package name: conda


usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...
conda: error: argument command: invalid choice: '/home/user/miniconda3/bin/conda' (choose from 'info', 'help', 'list', 'search', 'create', 'install', 'update', 'upgrade', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'config', 'clean', 'package')
```

or if I try to install conda directly:

```
$ conda install conda=4.5
Fetching package metadata ...................

CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError: Could not find environment: /home/user/miniconda3/envs/base .
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.

usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...
conda: error: argument command: invalid choice: '/home/user/miniconda3/bin/conda' (choose from 'info', 'help', 'list', 'search', 'create', 'install', 'update', 'upgrade', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'config', 'clean', 'package')
```

How can I get back to a more recent version of conda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error results from the change between conda 4.3 and 4.4 to rename the "main" environment from `root` to `base`. Note that the error message shows that conda is looking for an environment named `base` in the `envs` directory, when the `base` environment is not actually in that directory. If you specify a prefix, you can fix this problem:

```
conda install conda=4.5 -p /home/user/miniconda3
```